# JPA and DTO's, best way to create DTO's?

Tags: java, hibernate, orm, jpa, dto

We're to use DTO's to send data to and from the presentation layer.

I have a method on a service object called `PostAd` which posts an advertisement entered by a user.  The `Ad` has an association to another object called `AdValues`, which contain values for the `Ad` (title, price, description etc)

```
@Entity
public class Ad {
   @OneToMany
   Set<AdValue> values ...
   ...
```

I'm wondering what is better as far as the DTO architecture goes:

1. have two DTO's one called `AdDTO` and the other called `AdValuesDTO` and call the `PostAd` method as `PostAd(AdDTO, AdValuesDTO)` **~or~**
2. Have an `AdDTO` that contains the `AdValuesDTO` mimicking the entity structure... this involves having DTO's within DTO's:

   ```
   AdDTO {
     Set<AdValuesDTO> adValues ...
   ```

Then the `PostAd` method is called as `PostAd(AdDTO)`

Or is there another alternative?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both would work but with the later approach, you could also use the DTOs to send data **from** the server to the client. And since having DTOs is already hard and expensive to maintain, you don't really want to multiply them like Jesus with bread.

So, to my experience, when you use DTOs, you actually end up having a symmetric structure in parallel of your Entities that you can use in both directions between the client and server. And this makes the use of a mapping solution like [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/)  possible, or at least easier (and anything that makes using DTOs less painful is welcome).

Comment: thanks, i took your advice, added dozer to my POM, and managed to delete 75% of the boiler plate code..

Comment: One hint: stay away from Dozer. It requires you to break encapsulation and when something fails it is at runtime instead of compile time. It is currently based on xml (=xml hell). And last but not least: Dozer is sloooooow...